# How To cover remaining space between two division vertically

Tags: html, css

Here is the CSS I have applied CSS to wrapper, header and footer, and I tried to cover the remaining part of the screen with the between container but I am not able to do it.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.between {}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="between"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `display: flex` for this, use `flex:1` to the child you want to take up available space.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}

.between {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  background: yellow;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="between"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

read more about [css flexbox box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) here.